# Get string value from QueryMultiple result

Tags: model-view-controller, .net-core

In my `dotNetCore` project, I've a query that returns multiple resultsets by using `QueryMultiple`...

This is my query

```
var sql = @"SELECT CountryId as Id, CountryName as Name FROM country;
            SELECT CityId as Id, CityName as Name, CountryId FROM city;
            SELECT CitizenshipId as Id, CitizenshipName as Name FROM citizenship;
            Select Count(user.UserId) as totalUserCount
                            FROM identityuser user;";
```

This is how I'm getting its result into variable

```
 using (IDbConnection dbConnection = new DbManager().Connection)
            {
                dbConnection.Open();

                var grid = dbConnection.QueryMultiple(sql, new
                {
                });

                manageProfileView.countries = grid.Read<Country>().ToList();
                manageProfileView.cities = grid.Read<City>().ToList();
                manageProfileView.nationalities = grid.Read<CitizenShip>().ToList();
            }
```

Now how could I get data of this query

> Select Count(user.UserId) as totalUserCount
>                                   FROM identityuser user;

I've tried something like this

> var userCount = grid.Read().ToList();

But its not returning valid data, Is there any better way to get simple count from `grid` variable.

Comment: userCount[0] will give the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you just need to get the corresponding Count of your List, try:

```
var userCount = grid.Read().ToList().Count;
```

Comment: and what If I've query like `select username from usertable wehre userId =1` how could I get its result from grid?